# Ubuntu Mate on RPi 3 to display webapp

Tags: mate, lxde, webapps

I have installed Ubuntu Mate on a RPi 3, which is attached to a full hd touchscreen. The setup is solely dedicated to displaying (and interacting with) a HTML/JS webapp. Except, this is painfully slow. I suspect `webapp-container` to be a huge CPU hog. This is pretty much confirmed by `top`.

After following a guide that tweaked the clocking and memory options on the RPi this got a bit better. The same guide (can't find it anymore) suggested installing LDXE instead of the MATE desktop environment. I should mention I have *no* experience with Linux dekstop environments and stuff.

Tips on RPi tweaking are welcome, but I specifically chose *askubuntu* instead of the RPi Stack Exchange. My main question is: *are there any options to speed up `webapp-container` or are there viable replacement options?* I have not yet figured out how to compile a QT WebApp myself (this would at least get rid of the chrome stuff that is still loaded with `webapp-container`, whilst not being used/displayed since the app is supposed to run in fullscreen mode).

Other things that might help me are suggestions on stripping down to the bare minimum. Are there command that uninstall all the default software packages and other unnecessary, bloated packages? Maybe I can get rid of the complete LXDE env and have some sort of monitor that relaunches the webapp when closed and on boot, I do need TeamViewer Host to allow me to login remotely. I do not have physical access to the machine.

Some constraints:

- I do not have physical access and I am not able to reinstall or change OS
- I do have SSH and TeamViewer access (since I was not able to setup VNC)
- Webapp is pretty huge, so I don't have the option to switch to a dedicated app
- All I want to do is improve the speed, prevent lagging (some CSS animations and such) and improve reactiveness, nothing else matters. Quick and dirty is fine by me, as long as the system stays stable (ok might be a contradiction here)..